# Who is correct here, GCC or MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, namespaces, name-lookup

Suppose we have this structure:

```
namespace some_namespace::types {
    using foo_t = int;
}

namespace some_namespace::classes {
    class bar {
    public:
        auto do_stuff() -> types::foo_t;
    };
}

using namespace some_namespace::classes;

auto bar::do_stuff() -> types::foo_t {
    return 1;
}
```

This code compiles happily in GCC6.
On the other hand, VS15 with the `/std:c++latest` switch enabled doesn't recognize the return type of `do_stuff`. It returns [C2653](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C2653)&rd=true).

Now, what I find highly suspicious is that this gets fixed by changing the second half to this:

```
using namespace some_namespace;

auto classes::bar::do_stuff() -> types::foo_t {
    return 1;
}
```

which in my eyes should be equal. Am I mistaken in thinking that this is a MSVC bug? What does the standard say about this?

Comment: Nope just GCC and MSVC implementing a new standard at different rates and with different priorities.

Comment: I think GCC is just being more lenient.

Comment: MSVC C++17 support: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten interesting, thank you. Doesn't this contradict [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/compiler-improvements-in-vs-2015-update-3-rc/)? Quote: *it’s supported in Update 3 today under the /std:c++latest switch*

Comment: Surely you can simplify this into one file, not four?

Comment: @T.C. I see your concern, but unfortunatly I was not able to reproduce the MSVC error when using one file.

Comment: [Really](https://godbolt.org/g/RXWCLI)?

Comment: @T.C. Thank you very much! Edited the question.

Comment: Can't find anything on the `nested-name-specifier` in [the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udir) about bringing it's namespaces in the using namespace but it's *somewhere* there.

Comment: Admittedly, I haven't read through the nested namespace specification in any detail, but I would expect that this shouldn't compile. Using a child namespace shouldn't use its parents. So how would the compiler know that `types::foo_t` really means `some_namespace::types::foo_t` in the function definition?

Comment: Please [file a bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/) and post a link here so we may upvote it. :-]

Comment: @NicolBolas [basic.lookup.unqual]/8. Names after the declarator-id are looked up as if they were in a member function body, i.e., in the class first and then in the class's enclosing namespaces.

Comment: @ildjarn oh wow, didn't expect a direct answer from you! Thanks a bunch for your work :)  
I opened [this bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3112044). Btw, does the website support some kind of hyperlink syntax? Don't want the URL floating in the air like that.

Comment: @T.C. Do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the C++17 feature, which didn't touch using-directives, nor indeed with using-directives at all. MSVC produces the same error from

```
namespace some_namespace{
    namespace types {
        using foo_t = int;
    }
    namespace classes {
        class bar {
        public:
            auto do_stuff() -> types::foo_t;
        };
    }
}

using some_namespace::classes::bar;

auto bar::do_stuff() -> types::foo_t {
    return 1;
}
```

[[basic.lookup.unqual]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lookup.unqual#8):

> For the members of a class `X`, a name used [...] in the definition of
>   a class member outside of the definition of `X`, following the
>   member's *declarator-id*, shall be declared in one of the following
>   ways:
>
> - before its use in the block in which it is used or in an enclosing block ([stmt.block]), or
> - shall be a member of class `X` or be a member of a base class of `X` ([class.member.lookup]), or
> - [...two bullet points about nested and local classes omitted...]
> - if `X` is a member of namespace `N` [...], before the use of the name, in namespace `N` or in one of `N`'s enclosing namespaces.

Name lookup for `types` should first look inside `bar`, then inside `classes`, then inside `some_namespace`. That last one should find the namespace `types`.